# dataframe count frequency of a string in a column

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a csv that contains 1000 rows in a python code and returning a new dataframe with 3 columns:
`noOfPeople` and `Description`, `Location`
My final `df` will be like this one:

```
 id  companyName  noOfPeople  Description  Location
 1    comp1       75          tech         USA
 2    comp2       22          fashion      USA
 3    comp3       70          tech         USA
```

I want to write a code that will stop once I have 200 rows where `noOfPeople` is greater or equal to 70 and it will return all the rest rows empty. So the code will count columns where `noOfPeople >=70`. Once I have 200 rows that has this condition, the code will stop.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df['noOfPeople'] >= 70].iloc[:200]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use head or iloc for select first 200 values and then get max:
print (df1['noOfPeople'].iloc[:199].max())
And add your filter what ever you need.